# Ajax não retorna texto em utf-8

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Por ajax, estou a fazer uma consulta a Base de dados, mas se o campo tiver caracteres especiais, eles aparecem mal. Estou a fazer o pedido na seguinte função JS, o resultado é mostrado numa div com o id="txtHint"

```
<script charset="UTF-8">
    function getProdutosSeccao(){
        var idSeccao = $('#id_seccao').val();
        if (idSeccao=="") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/getprodutos_seccao.php?q="+idSeccao,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

No documento ajax/getprodutos_seccao.php tenho o seguinte:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

require("ligar_ajax.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_produtos WHERE id_seccao = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo '<select name="id_produto" style="width: 100%;" id="id_produto">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['id_produto']."'>".$row['nome']."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Funciona tudo bem, só tenho o problema dos caracteres especiais aparecerem mal. Como posso contornar esta questão?

Comment: O charset da base é utf8?

Comment: sim sim, toda a página está em utf-8, menos o valor retornado pelo ajax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coloque no arquivo `ajax/getprodutos_seccao.php` o cabeçalho para `utf8` e na sua conexão mude também para `utf8` (`mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8")`). Fiz alterações no seu código.

```
<?php
    header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    require("ligar_ajax.php");

    //mudando o charset para utf8 na conexão
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8")

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_produtos WHERE id_seccao = '".$q."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    echo '<select name="id_produto" style="width: 100%;" id="id_produto">';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['id_produto']."'>".$row['nome']."</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
    mysqli_close($con);
```

*Referências:*

- [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)
- [Problemas com acentuação no AJAX, como resolver](http://wbruno.com.br/ajax/problemas-acentuacao-ajax-como-resolver/)

Comment: Era mesmo isso, Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Caso os passos do Harry Potter não ajudem tem uma solução mais "na marra" que é usando as funções do php para converter e "desconverter" em utf8.

Você pode imprimir os itens utilizando utf8_encode() e utf8_decode() dependendo da sua necessidade.

Exemplo:

```
echo "<option value='".utf8_encode($row['id_produto'])."'>".utf8_encode($row['nome'])."</option>";
```